# Product and Sum Type Parallels in Haskell Type Classes

Tags: haskell, typeclass, applicative, arrows, alternative-functor

It appears that type classes such as [Applicative](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base/docs/Control-Applicative.html#t:Applicative), [Monad](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base/docs/Prelude.html#t:Monad) and [Arrow](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base/docs/Control-Arrow.html#t:Arrow) have some sort of sum type equivalent in type classes such as [Alternative](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base/docs/Control-Applicative.html#t:Alternative), [MonadPlus](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base/docs/Control-Monad.html#t:MonadPlus) and [ArrowPlus](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base/docs/Control-Arrow.html#t:ArrowPlus) respectively. For example, Applicative and Alternative can be used to define the following:

```
(<&&>) :: Applicative f => f a -> f b -> f (a, b)
a <&&> b = (,) <$> a <*> b

(<||>) :: Alternative f => f a -> f b -> f (Either a b)
a <||> b = (Left <$> a) <|> (Right <$> b)
```

However, in all of these cases (as well as with [ArrowChoice](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base/docs/Control-Arrow.html#t:ArrowChoice)), the product type class is a prerequisite for the sum type class. Are there type class rules or common functions that depend on the prerequisite class? The [Typeclassopedia](https://wiki.haskell.org/Typeclassopedia) touches on these relationships, but unfortunately I couldn't find any explicit reason for the dependency.

Comment: It may be the case that it's impossible to be a Sum without being a Product, but being a Sum alone is possible.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`Arrow` is basically the class for [monoidal categories](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monoidal_category)<sup>1</sup> – with “monoid” not referring to `Monoid`, but the *product-monoid of Haskell types*. I.e., with unit element `()` and multiplication `(,)`. Now, sum types make up a monoid as well, and that's what `ArrowChoice` uses. These two classes are in that sense complementary; `ArrowChoice` shouldn't really be a subclass of `Arrow`.

In a monoidal category, you can then go on to have [monoidal functors](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monoidal_functor). How these come out depends on what you use as your type-monoid. For `(), (,)`, you get

```
class ProdMonoidalFtor f where
  prodUnit :: () -> f ()
  prodZip :: (f a, f b) -> f (a,b)

type (+) = Either
class SumMonoidalFtor f where
  sumUnit :: Void -> f Void
  sumZip :: f a + f b -> f (a+b)
```

Turns out the latter is basically useless, because `Void` is the [initial object](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Initial_and_terminal_objects) of **Hask**, meaning there exists exactly one `Void -> a` (namely [`absurd`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/void-0.7/docs/Data-Void.html#v:absurd)) for *all* types `a`. However, what does make some sense is *comonoidal functors* with `+`:

```
class SumCoMonoidalFtor f where
  sumCounit :: f Void -> Void -- I bet you find this useless too, but it's not totally.
  sumCozip :: f (a+b) -> f a + f b
```

That in turn wouldn't make sense for product types, because `()` is the *terminal* object.

What's interesting now is that `ProdMonoidalFtor` is equivalent to `Applicative`:

```
instance (ProdMonoidalFtor f) => Applicative f where
  pure x = fmap (const x) $ prodUnit ()
  fs <*> xs = fmap (\(f,x) -> f x) $ prodZip (fs,xs)
```

One might then suspect that `Alternative` is equivalent to `SumMonoidalFtor`, but it's not! Actually, it is equivalent to [decisive functors](http://www.reddit.com/r/haskell/comments/qsrmq/coapplicative_functor/), which are to [comonads](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/comonad-4.2.5/docs/Control-Comonad.html) as applicatives are to monads.

Whereas `Alternative` and `MonadPlus` don't really seem to have much mathematical backing, they're essentially what you get when “un-Kleisliing” the `ArrowChoice` class, but using the Kleisli category that arises from `ProdMonoidalFtor`. It's all a bit dubious.

---

<sup>1</sup><sub>That's considering only `first`/`left`, `second`/`right`, and `***`/`+++`. As for the remaining `&&&`, `|||` and `arr`, these are more specific and IMO belong [in seperate classes](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/constrained-categories-0.2.0.0/docs/Control-Arrow-Constrained.html).</sub>

Comment: `sumZip` is also pointless since you can have `either (fmap Left) (fmap Right)`, right?

Comment: @chi: I suppose so, but I'm not sure about the proof.